# Running portable executable in memory using the WinApi - C Programming

Tags: c, winapi

After searching for a way to run a portable executable in memory, I have stumbled upon the same piece of code in around 10 different projects, all with the same black magic hard coded numbers. I refactored it the best I could along with some error handling, here is the final result:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <Windows.h>

unsigned long run_portable_executable(unsigned char* binary)
{
    int success = 1, rc = 0;
    const uintptr_t binary_address = (uintptr_t)binary;
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* const dos_header = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)binary;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* const nt_header = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)(binary_address + dos_header->e_lfanew);

    if (nt_header->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE) {
        rc = 1;
        goto out;
    }

    STARTUPINFOW startup_info;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info;

    SecureZeroMemory(&startup_info, sizeof(startup_info));
    SecureZeroMemory(&process_info, sizeof(process_info));

    wchar_t current_file_path[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, current_file_path, MAX_PATH);

    success = CreateProcessW(current_file_path, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &startup_info, &process_info);

    if (!success)
        goto out;

    CONTEXT* const ctx = (CONTEXT*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(ctx), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    ctx->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;

    success = GetThreadContext(process_info.hThread, ctx);

    if (!success)
        goto out;

    uintptr_t* image_base;
    void* const modified_ebx = (void*)(ctx->Ebx + 8);
    success = ReadProcessMemory(process_info.hProcess, modified_ebx, &image_base, 4, NULL);

    if (!success)
        goto out;

    void* const binary_base = VirtualAllocEx(process_info.hProcess, (void*)(nt_header->OptionalHeader.ImageBase),
        nt_header->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    success = WriteProcessMemory(process_info.hProcess, binary_base, binary, nt_header->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL);

    if (!success)
        goto out;

    const uintptr_t binary_base_address = (uintptr_t)binary_base;

    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < nt_header->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; ++i) {
        IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* section_header = (IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*)(binary_address + dos_header->e_lfanew + 248 + (i * 40));
        void* const virtual_base_address = (void*)(binary_base_address + section_header->VirtualAddress);
        void* const virtual_buffer = (void*)(binary_address + section_header->PointerToRawData);

        success = WriteProcessMemory(process_info.hProcess, virtual_base_address, virtual_buffer, section_header->SizeOfRawData, 0);

        if (!success)
            goto out;
    }

    success = WriteProcessMemory(process_info.hProcess, modified_ebx, (void*)&nt_header->OptionalHeader.ImageBase, 4, 0);

    if (!success)
        goto out;

    ctx->Eax = binary_base_address + nt_header->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;

    success = SetThreadContext(process_info.hThread, ctx);

    if (!success)
        goto out;

    success = ResumeThread(process_info.hThread);

    if (!success)
        goto out;

out:
    return !success ? GetLastError() : rc;
}
```

This works perfectly fine, however, I do not understand several parts.

What does the following pointer point to:

```
void* const modified_ebx = (void*)(ctx->Ebx + 8);
```

I am assuming it has to do with the `ebx` stack register, but why is it being increased by 8 bytes, what is it supposed to represent?

The next thing that bothered me was the following:

```
(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*)(binary_address + dos_header->e_lfanew + 248 + (i * 40));
```

My guess would be every file header section is 40 bytes, which explains the `i * 40`, but why the `248` offset? Where do these values come from? If there is a specific structure that explains these offsets, I would appreciate if someone could let me know so I could replace it with the proper `sizeof()`.

Comment: You probably will find the answers buried in Microsoft's documentation on the portable executable format.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Dave Thank you for the link, this is going to be a painful read...

Comment: [Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx) is a lot more accessible, although it doesn't include information on the PE32+ format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> void* const modified_ebx = (void*)(ctx->Ebx + 8);

When `RtlUserThreadStart` is called in the main thread of the new created process, `ebx` points to the `PEB` structure, where offset 8 points to `ImageBaseAddress`. You can read more about the `PEB` offsets [here](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/ntdll/structs/peb/index.htm).

> (IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*)(binary_address + dos_header->e_lfanew + 248 + (i * 40));

248 (0xF8) is the fixed offset from the beginning of PE header to the sections, when indeed  every section length is 40 bytes. You can read more about it [here](http://www.sunshine2k.de/reversing/tuts/tut_pe.htm).

Comment: It seems that your second link hasn't been updated since 2002. So the offsets may have changed in Windows 10.